# Running the same app on several devices simultaneously

Tags: android

I want to run one app on two phones, and then display what these apps show onto the same tablet. Is this possible?

So for example show what phone #1 shows in the bottom left corner of the tablet screen and show what phone #2 shows in the bottom right corner.

All related answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is mirroring both phones screens, I know you can do it to your pc, not sure about tablets.
you can read more about this [here](http://gusclass.com/blog/2013/03/18/mirroring-android-ui-for-screencasts-and-demos/)

**But** from my experience, mirroring not working so good- in most of the solution you have to root the devices first, and it's probably be bit slow and not smooth.

I would recommend you just to put those 2 phones next to each other and make a video with the tablet.

Comment: I'll read up on the mirroring, although the video solution wont work for me, since I need the screen to be behind the phones. But I could replace the tablet with a laptop I to make it work.. Thanks alot!